# How to pass JobParameters to myBatisPagingItemReader without using @StepScope

Tags: spring-batch

I am using spring batch restart functionality so that it reads from the last failed point forward. My restart works fine as long as I don't use `@StepScope` annotation to my `myBatisPagingItemReader` bean method.

I have to use `@StepScope` so that i can do late binding to get the jobParameters using the input parameter to my myBatisPagingItemReader bean method
    `@Value("#{JobParameters['run-date']}"))`

If I use `@StepScope` the restart does not work.

I tried adding listener `new JobParameterExecutionContextCopyListener()` to copy JobParameters to ExecutionContext.
But how will i get access to ExecutionContext inside myBatisPagingItemReader as I don't have ItemReader's open methods?

Not sure how i can get access to jobParameters when running myBatisPagingItemReader without using `@StepScope`? Please any inputs.

Also not sure if my understanding on spring-batch restart is correct on how it works when new instance (stateful) is used when using `@StepScope`.

```
@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class BatchConfig {
    @Bean
    public Step step1(StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory,
        ItemReader<Model> myBatisPagingItemReader,
        ItemProcessor<Model, Model> itemProcessor,
        ItemWriter<Model> itemWriter) {

        return stepBuilderFactory.get("data-load")
            .<Model, Model>chunk(10)
            .reader(myBatisPagingItemReader)
            .processor(itemProcessor)
            .writer(itemWriter)
            .listener(itemReadListener())
             .listener(new JobParameterExecutionContextCopyListener())
            .build();
   }

   @Bean
    public Job job(JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory, @Qualifier("step1") 
               Step step1) {
           return jobBuilderFactory.get("load-job")
            .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
            .start(step1)
            .listener(jobExecutionListener())
            .build();
      }
}

@Component
public class BatchInputReader {

    @Bean
    //@StepScope
    public ItemReader<Model> myBatisPagingItemReader(
             SqlSessionFactory sqlSessionFactory) {
         MyBatisPagingItemReader<Model> reader = new 
         MyBatisPagingItemReader<>();
         Map<String, Object> parameterValues = new HashMap<>();
     // populate parameterValues  from jobParameters ??
         reader.setSqlSessionFactory(sqlSessionFactory);
         reader.setParameterValues(parameterValues);
         reader.setQueryId("query");
         return reader;
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are declaring a Spring Bean (`myBatisPagingItemReader`) in a Class annotated with `@Component` (`BatchInputReader`). This is not correct.

What you need to do is to declare the mybatis reader as a bean in your configuration class `BatchConfig`. Once this is done and the bean is annotated with `@StepScope`, you can pass pass job parameters as follows:

```
@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class BatchConfig {

    @Bean
    @StepScope
    public ItemReader<Model> myBatisPagingItemReader(
            SqlSessionFactory sqlSessionFactory,
            @Value("#{jobParameters['param1']}") String param1,
            @Value("#{jobParameters['param2']}") String param2) {
        MyBatisPagingItemReader<Model> reader = new
                MyBatisPagingItemReader<>();
        Map<String, Object> parameterValues = new HashMap<>();
        // populate parameterValues  from jobParameters ?? => Those can be now accessed from method parameters
        reader.setSqlSessionFactory(sqlSessionFactory);
        reader.setParameterValues(parameterValues);
        reader.setQueryId("query");
        return reader;
    }

    @Bean
    public Step step1(StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory,
                      ItemReader<Model> myBatisPagingItemReader,
                      ItemProcessor<Model, Model> itemProcessor,
                      ItemWriter<Model> itemWriter) {

        return stepBuilderFactory.get("data-load")
                .<Model, Model>chunk(10)
                .reader(myBatisPagingItemReader)
                .processor(itemProcessor)
                .writer(itemWriter)
                .listener(itemReadListener())
                .listener(new JobParameterExecutionContextCopyListener())
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Job job(JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory, @Qualifier("step1")
            Step step1) {
        return jobBuilderFactory.get("load-job")
                .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
                .start(step1)
                .listener(jobExecutionListener())
                .build();
    }
}
```

More details about this in the [Late Binding of Job and Step Attributes](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/4.1.x/reference/html/step.html#late-binding) section. `BatchInputReader` will be left empty and is not needed anymore. Less is more! :-)

Hope this helps.

Comment: I have put this bean myBatisPagingItemReader() as suggested to Configuration annotated class. I still have issue getting restart working. When I use StepScope annotation, the restart functionality does not start from the failed chunk onwards, instead it starts from start, as step scope creates a new instance of myBatisPagingItemReader.   Creating object in scope=step, name=scopedTarget.myBatisPagingItemReader,

Answer (score 0):

Adding to my question. I have added myBatisPagingItemReader() as suggested to my configuration annoated class.

Restart example when I use @Stepscope annotaton to myBatisPagingItemReader(), the reader is fetching 5 records and I have chunk size(commit-interval) set to 3.

**Job Instance - 01 - Job Parameter - 01/02/2019.**
chunk-1:
- process record-1
- process record-2
- process record-3
writer - writes all 3 records
chunk-1 commit successful

chunk-2: 
    process record-4
    process record-5 - Throws and exception
Job completes and set to 'FAILED' status

**Now the Job is Restarted again using same Job Parameter.

Job Instance - 01 - Job Parameter - 01/02/2019.**
chunk-1:
    process record-1
    process record-2
    process record-3
writer - writes all 3 records
chunk-1 commit successful

chunk-2:
    process record-4
    process record-5 - Throws and exception
Job completes and set to 'FAILED' status

Please note: Here as I am using @Stepscope annotation on myBatisPagingItemReader() bean method, the job creates a new instance , see below log message.
    *Creating object in scope=step, name=scopedTarget.myBatisPagingItemReader

    Registered destruction callback in scope=step, name=scopedTarget.myBatisPagingItemReader*
As it is new instance it start the process from start, instead of starting from chunk-2.

If i don't use Stepscope, it restarts from chunk-2 as the restarted job step sets - MyBatisPagingItemReader.read.count=3.

I would like to use Stepscope to use the late bindings, if i use stepscope, is it possible for my myBatisPagingItemReader to set the read.count from the last failure to get restart working?

Or
If I don't use @Stepscope, is there a way to get job parameters inside myBatisPagingItemReader?

Comment: Please don't add an answer with another question in it (See [Asking](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking)) even if it is related to the first question. You can open another question and I will be happy to help.

Comment: My initial question was how to pass JobParameters to myBatisPagingItemReader without using @StepScope. As if i use stepscope the restart feature does not work.